# Jsoup or Java č and ć

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to write some simple web crawler but have problem with words that contains č or ć. Those letters are common in my language. If i have word that doesn't contain those letter crawler works, but if i search with  č or ć no results. If i could get result and convert č and ć into c i could solve my problems. Is there anyway i can do that?
Web pages that i'm trying to crawl are using cp-1250 encoding.
Here is the code:

```
package crawler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

/**
 *
 * @author Anak1n
 */
public class Crawler {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String url = "http://www.b92.net";

        String pre = "a[href]:contains";
        String prvaZagrada = "(";
        String drugaZagrada = ")";
        System.out.print("Unesite rec koju trazite");
        String rec = input.next();

        String sve = pre + prvaZagrada + rec + drugaZagrada;
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        Elements a = doc.select(sve);

        String c = a.toString();

        if (c.length() == 0) {
            System.out.print("nema rezultata");
        } else {

            String zameni = "\\s*\\bamp;\\b\\s*";
            if (c.contains("amp;")) {
                c = c.replaceAll(zameni, "");
            }
            int d = c.lastIndexOf("");

            int start = c.indexOf("\"") + "\"".length();
            int end = c.indexOf("\"", start);
            String v = c.substring(start, end);

            if (url.contains("b92")) {
                System.out.println("http://www.b92.net" + v);
            } else if (url.contains("novosti")) {
                System.out.print("http://www.novosti.rs" + v);
            } else if (url.contains("kurir")) {
                System.out.print("http://www.kurir-info.rs" + v);
            } else if (url.contains("danas")) {
                System.out.print("http://www.danas.rs" + v);
            } else {
                System.out.print(v);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

EDIT: Problem is with Scanner. I wont use Scanner in my application i was only testing it before building GUI.

Comment: It is not clear what works or what does not work - can you give a more specific example?

Comment: If you type snow(on my language sneg) it is working it gives back link which contains word snow, but if you type for example Čekao it can not find anything but it exist on web page.

Comment: ok, so the problem would be in `Elements a = doc.select(sve);` ? Could you show a simple example that people can copy, paste and run?

Comment: This can be run. Copy paste run and type "gotova" without quotes and u will get link. Try with "Žestoka" and u wont get a hit.

Comment: You should see what are the actual contents of those elements. Do they actually contain č and ć?

Comment: Yes they contain all the letters č,ć,š,đ,ž                          <a title="Vavrinka odveo Švajcarsku na 2-0" href="/sport/tenis/vesti.php?yyyy=2014&mm=01&dd=31&nav_id=806668"></a>

Comment: Problem is with Scanner. So i'm intending to build gui so it is not a problem. Ty for your effort.

Comment: I tried with Švajcarsku and I get http://www.b92.net/sport/tenis/vesti.php?yyyy=2014&mm=01&dd=31&nav_id=806668

Comment: Tried again with ŽIVOT, get a url http://www.b92.net/zivot/. Your code works just fine for me

Comment: It worked with "svedočio" as well... so it's not reproducible.

Comment: Add System.out.print(doc.text()); u must get šđčć in words like uživo, lečenje and so on. I said it is not a problem it was Scanner fault and i would not use him. If i try String rec = "Život" i get a hit.

Comment: I deleted that comment; I had "whole words" search option on by accident. As I said, I can successfully search for "svedočio" and "Knežević".

Comment: U are using eclipse or netBeans?

Comment: Then the problem is in NetBeans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your problem has mostly been reduced to an issue with the IDE's console, in the process of reproducing it I have simplified your original code. You may find it useful:

```
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
  System.out.print("Unesite rec koju trazite");
  final Elements result = Jsoup.connect("http://www.b92.net").get()
        .select("a[href]:contains(" + input.next() + ")");
  System.out.println(result.size() > 0?
      result.get(0).attr("href") : "nema rezultata");
}
```

Comment: Additional note: no need to `replace("&amp;", "&")` because that's already taken care of when you access `href` through `attr` method.